# How do I get a particular python module to work in Anaconda?

Tags: python

I don't have a lot of programming experience, so please try to keep answers relatively noob-friendly! :) Basically, I have a Python...library, I guess? or module? that I need to run in Spyder through Anaconda. This seems to be a very obscure module called PySPM, used for analyzing scanning probe microscopy data, that I received from a colleague my lab collaborates with. When I try to run a piece of software which uses this module, it gives this error:

```
    ImportError: No module named 'PySPM.io'
```

The code itself which triggers this reads as follows:

```
    from os import path
    from PySPM.io.Translators.Utils import uiGetFile
    from PySPM.io.Translators.BEPSndfTranslator import BEPSndfTranslator
    from PySPM.io.Translators.BEodfTranslator import BEodfTranslator
    from PySPM.analysis.BESHOFitter import BESHOFitter
```

The first line that says `from PySPM.io.Translators.Utils import uiGetFile` is what's triggering the error. I'm really stuck scratching my head here. What's going on and how can I solve it?

Comment: The python executable that's running that code doesn't have access to the `PySPM.io` module. It needs to live in the PYTHONPATH relative to that executable.

Comment: Not everything comes with Anaconda or any other distribution of Python (I use Enthought Canopy, another scientific editor). You still have to install some things; does this help? http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-a-package

Comment: Install it with pip, `pip install pySPM`, pip is included with anaconda  and you can use it to install any  non conda packages http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-non-conda-packages

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Do you know the directory for Anaconda? For example, in Enthought Canopy on Windows it's `C:\Users\<your_name>\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages` and then `pip install <modulename>`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I tried using pip, but when I do that in CMD, I get the following:
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspm (from versions: )`
`No matching distribution found for pyspm`

Comment: @roganjosh, it has been an age since I used it, I also don't use windows but on linux it exports the path to your .bashrc file which was `home/user/anaconda/bin` by default.

Comment: @roganjosh: I confess that I don't really know what you mean. I definitely have Anaconda on my computer and have Spyder open, and I have Python 3.5 as well.

Comment: @AdamSmith: I think I take your meaning, but I am not sure how to actually put that into practice. I've tried copying and pasting the PySPM folder into various folders of Anaconda and I'm just not really seeing it do anything.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, in Linux it all seems much easier when I port code over. Perhaps you can do it without navigating to the main directory on Windows too, but I had issues. Martensite, you shouldn't have to copy/paste anything, pip and/or easy_install should put it on your Python Path. Martensite, try 'pySPM' instead?

Comment: @Martensite, try `pip install https://github.com/ssomnath/PySPM/archive/master.zip`, that will install using master from github

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I got this error when I tried running the most recent comment you added: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\conno\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-akst2up7-build\`

Comment: @Martensite, add the full traceback to pastebin

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Here you are - http://pastebin.com/3FNVv21m

Comment: OK, the package only works with python2, you are using anaconda3 which I presume uses python3

Comment: @roganjosh, from the error you can see that anaconda installs to `c:\users\user\anaconda3`

Comment: @Martensite, this is the pypi page for the package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pySPM it has only been downloaded twice in the past month which is pretty low, where did you hear about it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham upvoted your last comment because I think you got to the bottom of it. I don't use Anaconda but wondered if it worked a bit like Canopy when I've had problems in the past. Nice work mate :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I found that pypi page already, but since there wasn't any download link, I was unsure what to do. Does your statement about python2 mean that I will need to reinstall python using an older version? If so, how will I be able to run this after I do so (i.e., what will be different compared to trying it with Python 3)?

Comment: @Martensite, you can as far as I know set up an environment that uses python2, python3 is not backwards compatible so a package developed for python2 may not an often does not work for python3. The default for Anaconda3 is 3.5 http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#create-python-2-or-3-environments

Comment: So basically set up an environment specifying python2 as the version and try the procedure again with pip

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Apologies for the continued questions, but we seem to be approaching a solution. I can go ahead and install a version of Python 2, but I don't really know what setting up an environment is. I think this would be easy enough to figure out, but where do I copy/paste my folder containing the PySPM files to in order to get it to run it?

Comment: I actually meant a conda environment, it is in the link above, of course if you just want to install  python2 itself you can use an install, this link covers all you need to know https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html, but I would try the conda options first if you plan on using the scientific packages included

Comment: Apologies for the delay, as I was getting home and getting Python 2.7 installed. I'm really pretty lost on what exactly you're referring to, I'm afraid. I'm definitely not the most code-savvy, so I'm not quite clear on how to set up an environment, or what I should do once that environment is set up in order to try to get the PySPM running.

Comment: As an update, I tried running the `pip install https://github.com/ssomnath/PySPM/archive/master.zip` suggestion with Python 2.7 installed (after having uninstalled Python 3.x) and got this error: http://pastebin.com/1MzufUyq

Comment: @Martensite, just try installing with `pip install PySPM` the mster may be ahead of the pypi version and not be working, where did you get a reference to this lib?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, when I tried that I received the following familiar error: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySPM (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PySPM`

I didn't find the library online - a colleague of my research group's that works at Oak Ridge National Laboratory sent us the library as a .zip file and this is what I have available to me. It seems to contains everything that I need, but I don't really know what to..._do_ with it.

Comment: You can try installing the zip with pip or unpacking it to your dist-packages folder or add a custom path to you pythonpath,

Comment: I did not actually look at the source at all on github until now, the package is not even created yet, it is in the planning stage as listed on pypi Development Status :: 1 - Planning so I have no idea how your friends got it, if there is a `setup.py` file in the zip file the calling `pip install filename.zip` or `python setup.py install` should work

Comment: Upon further inspection, the colleague we have at ORNL is actually Suhas Somnath, one of the coauthors of the file. I have reached out to him for guidance as well. What is the dist-packages folder and the pythonpath?

Comment: I had a suspicion that may be the case,basically your pythonpath is where python will look for packages, try `import site;site.getsitepackages()` from a python shell and you will lsee that paths

Answer (score 0):

[Pycroscopy](https://pycroscopy.github.io/pycroscopy/about.html) is the (thoroughly) reorganized version of [PySPM](https://pypi.org/project/pySPM/).

@Martensite try:

```
$ pip install pycroscopy
```